# Parallel resistor not affecting rest of the circuit

Tags: resistors, analog, analysis, thevenin

I have been asked the following question:

> The resistance, r, is not known in fig(1a), why does its value not affect potential at b?

By [Thévenin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin's_theorem), any arbitrary voltage source can be replaced by ideal voltage source with a resistor in series (without affecting the rest of the circuit - rendering those two equivalent). However, I don't think that this is the answer they are looking for, neither I can think of any other way to explain why this resistor does not affect value of \$V_b\$. I have tried to do mesh-analysis, but that failed miserably.

Any other ways?

[image: Figure 1a]

Comment: r won't affect the voltage at a (unless it's a dead short). In practice, the supply will have some internal resistance, and the value of r will have an effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not going to just give you the answer to your homework problem.

However, consider what it really means to be a voltage source.  Let's say I have a 6V source that is good to 1 A.  What voltage is it when nothing is connected?  When I put a 60 Ω resistor accross it?  A 30 Ω resistor accross it?

If I put the 6 V source and resistor inside a black box and brought out only the two leads, what difference could someone observe on the outside to distinguish the no load, 60 Ω and 30 Ω cases?  Now consider this is the case you have.  Your +6V and R are inside the box and the rest of the circuit on the outside.

Comment: Thanks, it's clearer now :) Also, not a homework, just exercise sheets.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's redraw the schematic in a more intuitive way.

[image: schematic]

What we have here is a series parallel circuit. Assuming \$r>0\$ and the voltage source can supply enough current to meet the demand, \$V_c\$ is connected to the positive terminal node, so it must stay at that potential, and \$V_a\$ is connected to the negative node and must stay at that potential. \$V_b\$ can be determined by the voltage divider rule.

If \$r=0\$, the supply is shorted, and all nodes will go to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to throw Thévenin at this problem, then consider that the closest thing to an "ideal voltage source" is a power supply.  That is, your Thévenin model of the 6v source would be modeled with a zero ohm series resistance.